# How to set up to run r script on docker image using crontab

Tags: docker, cron, rstudio-server, amazon-lightsail

I installed rstudio on aws lightsail following by https://jrfarrer.github.io/r/2016/12/29/RStudio-Lightsail.html.
Now i am trying to run rscript every minute using by crontab or anything that run rscript regularly.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I assume you use the r-base image. If you just need your R script to run in the currently existing container, just create a new cron entry in your host using the `docker exec` command.

Example

```
* * * * * docker exec -it $instanceName Rscript yourScript.R
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i got the log "time="2017-11-02T16:33:01Z" level=fatal msg="Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/rstudio2/exec: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?" "

Comment: ohh sorry... You have to set it up in a user having the `docker` group defined

Comment: Thank you it helps alot.